# take snaps when entered wrong password

Tags: security, webcam, snapshot

hi a i am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS if anybody can help me with this, i want my webcam to take snaps of the person who is trying to enter my computer.it would be best if someone try to explain it in scripting language.i would like to make it a cron job so it can automatically when system is boot up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `motion` package to take pictures of moving objects seen by your webcam.

```
motion - V4L capture program supporting motion detection
```

Start `motion` as you leave your computer.

There is no way to get the `login` program to "do something" on single password failures.